# How to prove that a function has a point of inflexion when the function is in terms of constants only?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, stationary-point

Below is the question that I have been working with:
[image]

And here is the solution to part c), the part that I am stuck on:
[image]

Here’s the thing, I understand why the first two factors are greater than zero (see the solution above), but, not why the third factor is negative when delta is *added* to x.

Looking at the second factor, if b plus e to the power of negative c times x plus minus delta in brackets is greater than zero then shouldn’t the latter term be greater than minus b when you manipulate the equality? Then doesn’t that mean the factor dealt with last in the solution (see picture) can never be negative? (It was stated earlier that b is greater than zero.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"shouldn’t the latter term be greater than minus b when you manipulate the equality? Then doesn’t that mean the factor dealt with last in the solution (see picture) can never be negative"*. If $x$ is greater than something negative, that doesn't mean $x$ can't be negative. What they're using here is that $e^{-cx} = b$ at the point of inflection.

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen thank you for your comment. Look, what I mean is that if b + e^[-c(x+-d)] > 0 (as stated in the printed solution), then subtracting b from both sides would give e^[-c(x+-d)] > -b. So, how can they say that e^[-c(+d)] - b is smaller than zero (see third last row in solution)? e^[-c(x+d)] is greater than -b and both are postive so the difference should be positive..?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the question says that $b$ is positive, so that means that $-b$ is negative? Let's just write $z$ for $e^{-c(x + \delta)}$. If $z > -b$, it can still be the case that $z - b < 0$. For example, if $z = 1$, $b = 2$.

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen that makes a lot of sense, yes, you’re right. Thank you for clearing it up! Do you think you’d mind explain, just in a few words or sentences, the second last row from the bottom? I just think it’s a little weird that they’re stating it like that, as a fact, since f’’(x+d) can very well be positive eg if z=3 and b=2..?

Comment: That's where you have to use extra information you have, namely the fact that $f''(x) = 0$, so $e^{-cx} - b = 0$. If you increase $x$ a little bit, $-cx$ decreases a little bit, so $e^{-cx}$ decreases a little bit. That's why $e^{-c(x + \delta)} - b$ is negative.

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen ah, finally I understand, thank you so much! This question has caused me so much frustration... Again, thanks and have a great day. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

The point of inflexion is at $P\left(-\frac{\log (b)}{c},\frac{a}{2 b}\right)$

$$f''(x)>0\to b e^{c x}-1>0$$

$$x>-\frac{\log (b)}{c}$$
Therefore at $P$ concavity changes and this proves that $P$ is a point of inflexion.